# Find a customer usage for a given period of time

Tags: excel, calendar, formula

I have to bill a customer based on monthly usage however I'm only provided with a date range and total usage.  I need to calculate the average daily usage, then calculate the number of days in each for the bill period, then multiply the days in month by the average to get the number of 'x' to bill the customer.

For example.  I have two customers below and each has a different bill period and usage.

I'm given the data in Excel below.  I'm struggling to build a formula that will give me A) the number of days in each month, B) the average use per day, C) the total amount used in each month.  See the example below with how I calculate by hand.

```
Cell A1  Cell A2    Cell A3 
9/5/2017 10/4/2017  83
```

Example:

```
Billing Period 
Cust #1: 9/4/2017-10/4/2017 and usage is 85 
Cust #2: 9/11/2017-10/11/2017 and usage is 1065

Cust #1 
Sept Days is 27 
Oct Days is 4 
total days is 31 
Ave use per day 2.7 (85 divided by 31)
Answer:
**Sept Usage is 74 Oct Usage is 11**

Cust #1 
Sept Days is 20
Oct Days is 11 
total days is 31 
Ave use per day 34.35 (1065 divided by 31)
Answer:
**Sept Usage is 687 Oct Usage is 378**
```

Comment: is it always on two month spread or can it be more months than 2?

Comment: most of the time it is two months but on occasion it can have 3 months example 1/31/2018-3/2/2018.